# I want to apply for the UK registered traveller scheme but will it be a problem that my visa expires in less than 6 months?

Tags: visas, uk

I am an Australian passport holder with a UK Tier 1 visa. The visa is expiring in January next year and I will be renewing it later this year.

I want to apply for the registered traveller scheme but will it be a problem that my visa expires in less than 6 months? Also, if I am accepted as a registered traveller, does it expire with my current visa? Or do they issue it for 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

Membership lasts 12 months. According to the UK gov site https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller/renew-or-update-your-membership you can update your visa details free of charge during the membership period, so your visa expiry in 6 months should not be a problem.

Comment: what happens if I don't renew my visa? Am I still able to enter on a tourist visa as a registered traveller?